# ajax or not to ajax the first page on web?

Tags: ajax, web, dry

Suppose we show list of items for `/foo/` and support pagination via `/foo&page=2` and so on.
A user requests different pages using `/foo&page=2` via ajax.

1. I could make `/foo` (== `/foo&page=1`) return the complete html on requests so that page loads faster.
2. Or I could return the layout for `/foo` and, let the client to request the first page via ajax.

I guess #1 is better, but I guess I'm afraid of breaking DRY.
How do you handle this, ie, giving full contents for the first page and partial ajax requests for other pages, and not breaking the DRY?

Comment: Do you have any interest in search engines being able to crawl your item list?

Comment: Well then you will have to provide standard HTML versions of your output anyway.

Comment: you mean, entire page HTML or are you talking about HTML of the div instead of JSON for the div?

Comment: Search engines like to request complete HTML documents.

Comment: so something like pjax (https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) is not search engine friendly? I've seen an article which talks about SEO of ajax (e.g. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) havent' read myself, just bookmarked it.

Comment: Seeing that it says it provides _“real permalinks”_ and the rest of the description, I suppose it is – but it builds on top of a “regular” website that has the necessary structure in place already. (And that’s the way it _should_ be done.)